# Need help identifying a 3-pin "Molex" (ish) connector

Tags: connector, identification

I've been trying to figure out what type of connectors these are, so I can get a supply of them. They're 3-pin and fairly compact. I thought they were like the smaller computer fan 3-pin connectors, but those don't fit.

I purchased a digital caliper to take accurate measurements of the pitch etc, but I would prefer to avoid breaking my guitar strings to dig in there and do so at the moment.

I don't think they're real Molex brand connectors, but it's hard to be sure (these are from a guitar builder in Korea).

I've attached a few pictures that should hopefully help with identification. Thanks!

outside width: 8.58mm skinny part, 10.19mm thick

height: 3.84mm, 5.83mm

length: 20.99mm

pins 5mm total width

2.5mm between each pin

~.86mm pin?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are the markings on your ruler in inches or centimeters?

Comment: @Hop - Hi, The 1st and 3rd images *seem* to be identical. If you meant to include a different 3rd image, please can you replace the duplicate? Or if the 3rd image is an unintentional duplicate, can you please remove it? If the 3rd image really is different to the 1st, and is showing us something that the 1st image isn't showing, can you please add a little text telling us what extra detail we should be looking at, in that 3rd image? Thanks! That *looks like* a 0.5 mm scale & the outer pins at values 4.5 mm and 9.5 mm, so 5 mm between 3 pins = approx 2.5 mm (0.1"?) pin pitch. Is that correct?

Comment: Once you get a better number on the pitch of the pins, you can select "More Filters" here and do a search. https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/rectangular-connectors-housings/319?k=housing&k=&pkeyword=housing&sv=0&pv1989=0&pv88=169295&sf=1&FV=-8%7C319&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&stock=1&pageSize=25

Comment: Thanks all. Can't seem to replace the duplicate image on my phone so I'll do it in my computer later. The small ruler is indeed 0.5mm ticks. It looks like I'll have better luck after I open it back up and take measurements with calipers.

Comment: Okay, this is just for the connector with the visible pins because the other gender is harder to get to (the one on the 0.5mm ruler above):

outside width: 8.58mm skinny part, 10.19mm thick
height: 3.84mm, 5.83mm
length: 20.99mm

pins 5mm total width
2.5mm between each pin
~.86mm pin?